# How to make new line in mathematica file output?

Tags: files-and-directories, text, file-transfer, export

I know that new line is classically made by **"\n"**.

I want to make a string with lines of data and then export it into a file:

```
outString = StringJoin["First Line \nSecond Line"]
Put[outString, NotebookDirectory[] <> "testOut.txt"]
```

The first line, make a decent output in the Mathematica itself:

```
"First Line 
Second Line"
```

But in the testOut.txt file , it is :

```
"First Line \nSecond Line"
```

Note that it even includes the quotation marks and both in the same line !  What is the solution for that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Put[OutputForm[outString], "testOut.txt"]
```

[image]

compare with

```
Put[outString, "testOut0.txt"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Export`:

```
Export["testOut2.txt", outString]
(* or Export["testOut2.txt", outString, "Text"] *)
```

or, `WriteString` (thanks: Mr.Wizard)

```
strm = OpenWrite["testOut2.txt"];
WriteString[strm, outString]
Close[strm]
```

to get the same result:

[image]

Comment: Consider also mentioning `WriteString` +1

Comment: Thanks @Mr.W, added `WriteStream`.

Comment: Great !  Thank you

Comment: @kglr, is there any way to put linebreak inside `WriteString` long expression. WriteString by default writes expression(string) as a single line.

Comment: @Boogeyman, afaik we can't do it directly with `WriteString`. You can use [WriteLine](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteLine.html) instead.

Comment: @kglr, Agree for writing `String`. But I needed for some different purpose. I am writing a big expression in the form `double var = expr` for which I find `WriteString` convenient so far with only problem is that it writes the expression (`Text`) in a single line. May be I will open a new thread on this.