# How to write a string verbatim

Tags: output

I'm trying to write a function which takes some strings, manipulates them, and writes the result to a file.

Here's a small example which recreates the behavior I'm seeing:

```
writefile[instr1_, instr2_, filename_] := 
 Module[{str1, outstr, stream},
  str1 = "abc \n `` \n def \n ``";
  outstr = OutputForm[StringForm[str1, instr1, instr2]];
  Export[filename, outstr];
  ]
```

When I call `writefile["xyz", "pqr", "test.txt"]`, I would expect test.txt to have the output:

```
abc
xyz
def
pqr
```

However, it instead looks like this:

```
abc xyz     pqr
        def
```

What's going on?  I've tried the suggestions at [this SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80731/how-to-make-new-line-in-mathematica-file-outputhttps://), but they all give the same result.

When I remove the `OutputForm` call and simply return `outstr` in the function above, it prints to the screen just fine, but writing this to file means that the output file reads literally ``` StringForm["abc \n `` \n def \n ``", "xyz", "pqr"] ```.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not use `OutputForm`. Use [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html). This is sufficient to generate your string:

```
In[191]:= templ = StringTemplate["abc \n `` \n def \n ``"];

In[192]:= templ["xyz", "pqr"]
Out[192]= "abc 
 xyz 
 def 
 pqr"
```

Those extra spaces at the beginning of each line are there because you added them to the template, after each `\n`. Remove them if you don't want them.

You can now `Export` this string. It is a good idea to *always* specify the export format explicitly. Do not do `Export[filename, str]` because the export format will be inferred from the file name. Use `Export[filename, str, "String"]` for raw strings or `Export[filename, str, "Text"]` if you want to specify things like character encodings and line endings.

Comment: Thanks! this did it

Answer (score 3):

I think this would do what you want:

```
writefile[instr1_, instr2_, filename_] := 
 Module[{str1, outstr, stream}, 
  str1 = "abc\n" <> instr1 <> "\n" <> "def\n" <> instr2 <> "\n";
  outstr = OutputForm[StringForm[str1]];
  Export[filename, outstr];]
```

Calling this with

```
writefile["xyz", "pqr", "test.txt"]
```

Gives the following file contents (each is on a separate line): 
abc
xyz
def
pqr